# price showing with more then 2 decimals?

Tags: php, mysql, select, decimal, joomla3.0

My query results in a 6 decimal number (eg 3500,000000 instead of 3500,00).
For numbers with 2 decimals (eg. € 35,95) it must show last 2 decimals, otherwise without decimals (eg. € 60)

I hv try it another code without success (see code 2)

this is code 1 i use that shows result with 6 decimals eg. € 35,000000

```
<?php
    $query = 'SELECT `jr_prijs` FROM `zmuvr_jreviews_content` WHERE contentid = '.$item->getId();
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $result = $db->loadResult();
    print_r($result);
```

and this is code 2:

```
<?php function format_price($value) { return preg_replace( '/[.,]0{2,}/', '', strval($value) ); } ?>

 <?php
$query = 'SELECT `jr_prijs` FROM `zmuvr_jreviews_content` WHERE contentid = '.$item->getId();
$db->setQuery( $query );
$result = $db->loadResult();
print_r  (format_price  $result);
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simplified the question and corrected some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *always* want two decimals, then cast the value to `decimal(x, 2)`:

```
select cast(jr.prijs as decimal(10, 2)) . . .
```

If you want two decimals sometimes and none at others, then you need to convert the value to a string:

```
select format(jr.prijs,
              (case when jr.prijs - floor(jr.prijs) not between 0.005 and 0.995
                    then 0 else 2
               end)
              )
```

Comment: If `prijs` can be negative, we can use the `ABS` function to return the absolute value of the difference. MySQL doesn't have a builtin function named `trunc`....: **`case when ABS(jr.prijs - TRUNCATE(jr.prijs,0) not between `**

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . Oops, that should have been `floor()`.  Too much Oracle recently.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  
can you help where in mine code shall i paste your code ?

Comment: ooooo :)) sorry but this works  , the best method but thx to other helpers and oscargeek his method also works but i will show if actual last to decimals , this code was correct only not jr.prijs but it must be jr_prijs in mine case THX :))))

Comment: @GordonLinoff :))
Maybe latest one for this price problem :)
results show e.g € 3,999.95 ..............how can i show € 3 999.95 (space after 3 and without ¨,¨ or punktum
 if no decimals € 2 900,-
mean like french notation on php.net

Answer (score 0):

try to look on [roundFunction](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
$a = 3.54353543;
echo round($a,2); //this will print 3.54
```

if your number is a string, use first  [floatVal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)
that will parse string to number

Answer (score 0):

use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format($number,2);
```

Comment: Sotek 
i used this but error 
    `<?php
$number = 1234.56;

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>

<?php
    $query = 'SELECT `jr_prijs` FROM `zmuvr_jreviews_content` WHERE contentid = '.$item->getId();
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $result = $db->loadResult();
    print_r ( number_format($number,2); $result);
?>`

Comment: You cannot use `print_r ( number_format($number,2); $result);` instead use something like `print_r(number_format($number,2)); print_r($result);`

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer can be modified slightly.  Use his select

```
select cast(jr.prijs as decimal(10, 2)) . . .
```

but treat the result as well:

```
if ($result == round($result)) {
   $result = round($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT b, IF( ROUND(b,0) = ROUND(b,2),
                     ROUND(b,0),  ROUND(b,2) ) AS x
           FROM deci;
+-------+-------+
| b     | x     |
+-------+-------+
|  2.35 |  2.35 |
|  7.65 |  7.65 |
|  4.00 |     4 | -- Note how whole number comes out without trailing '.00'
|  0.30 |  0.30 |
|  0.44 |  0.44 |
|  2.22 |  2.22 |
| -4.40 | -4.40 |
```